# Finding first Excel column with no data using xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I have an workbook in Excel and I need to find the first column that is empty / has no data in it. I need to keep Excel open at all times, so something like `openpyxl` won't do.

Here's my code so far:

```
import xlwings as xw
from pathlib import Path

wbPath = Path('test.xlsx')

wb = xw.Book(wbPath)

sourceSheet = wb.sheets['source']
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet with using [`used_range`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Sheet.used_range) is more robust than using [`expand()`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.expand), as it gives you the first empty column at the very end of the data, regardless of empty/blank columns somewhere before the last column with data.
(`ws` means worksheet; in your case `sourceSheet`)

**First emtpy column as integer**

```
ws.used_range[-1].offset(column_offset=1).column
```

**First emtpy column as letter**

```
ws.used_range[-1].offset(column_offset=1).address.split("$")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using

```
destinationSheet["A1"].expand("right").last_cell.column
```